# No way to make it work with Slim framework

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, slim

I have a raspberry with Apache2.

In /var/www/ I have these files :

```
/myprojet
     /public_html
         index.php
         .htaccess
     /lib
         Slim
```

In index.php I have :

```
<?php

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/alertes.json', 'getalertes');

$app->run();

function getalertes() {
    $sql = "select * FROM T_ALERT ORDER BY name";
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
        $alertes = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo '{"alerte": ' . json_encode($alertes) . '}';
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}

function getConnection() {
    $dbhost="127.0.0.1";
    $dbuser="root";
    $dbpass="root";
    $dbname="db";
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbh;
}

?>
```

In .htaccess I have :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

In /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default I have :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/myproject/public_html"

        ErrorLog "/var/www/logs/error.log"

        <Directory "/var/www/myproject/public_html">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel debug

        CustomLog /var/www/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I go on the url :

```
http://192.168.1.99/myproject/alertes.json
```

I've got nothing, a blank page.
Did I miss something ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you enabled error reporting? Checked your logs? I suspect your documentroot is wrong.

Comment: the documentroot is good (i just changed it in my post ;) ), in the error.log I have : [Tue May 27 12:50:26 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.10] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Slim\\Slim' not found in /var/www/myproject/public_html/index.php on line 3
[Tue May 27 12:50:26 2014] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 192.168.1.10] Zlib: Compressed 0 to 2 : URL /index.php

Comment: Have you included the Slim files?

Comment: What do you mean ? I put the files in : /var/www/myproject/lib/Slim/
For example I have Slim.php, View.php, Route.php...etc

Comment: By putting "require '../lib/Slim/Slim.php';" in the beginning of the file, I have now a Slim 404 error when I call : http://192.168.1.99/myproject/alertes.json

Comment: Try 192.168.1.99/alertes.json

Comment: I've posted it as an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors. You need to require or include the Slim files and you need to use the URL 192.168.1.99/alertes.json.

Comment: Could you explain me why ? How could I configure htaccess to have access only with /watchit/alertes.json ?

Comment: In that case you would have to define the route in Slim `$app->get('/watchit/alertes.json' 'function');`

Comment: In fact, I think there is some wrong configuration in htaccess...
For example, if I have other projects in /var/www, none of them works now...